# How to return Result form an Activity to the MainActivity without using StartActivityForResult() method in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I have tried to return result from activity to the `MainActivity` without using the `StartActivityForResult()` and `OnActivityResult()` and `SetResult(Result_OK,intent)` etc.

I want to use only the `startActivity()` method and `putExtra()` and `getExtra()`? 
and i want to know what is the difference between `RequsetCode` and `ResultCode` in `OnActivityResult()` method ?!

this is the code that I want to convert it from this case to the case i want :

```
package com.example.explicitintentstartactivityforreswult;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText number1, number2, result1, result2;
    Button add, sub;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number1);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number2);
        result1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result1);
        result2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result2);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);


        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        sub.setOnClickListener(this);

    }












    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:

            Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add.class);
            I.putExtra("number1", number1.getText().toString());
            I.putExtra("number2", number2.getText().toString());



            startActivityForResult(I, 0);
            break;

        case R.id.sub:

            Intent II = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sub.class);
            II.putExtra("number1", number1.getText().toString());
            II.putExtra("number2", number2.getText().toString());
            startActivityForResult(II, 1);
            break;
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                result1.setText(data.getExtras().getString("result"));

            break;

        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                result2.setText(data.getExtras().getString("result"));

            break;
        }

    }

}



package com.example.explicitintentstartactivityforreswult;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Add extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText num1,num2;
    Button bt1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        num1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
        num2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);

        num1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("number1"));
        num2.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("number2"));

        bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cal1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(this);




    }    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int number1= Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
        int number2= Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());

        Intent I=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        I.putExtra("result", number1+number2+"");

        setResult(RESULT_OK, I);
        finish();

    }

}

package com.example.explicitintentstartactivityforreswult;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Sub extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText num1,num2;
    Button bt1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        num1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
        num2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);

        num1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("number1"));
        num2.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("number2"));

        bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cal1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(this);




    }    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int number1= Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
        int number2= Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());

        Intent I=new Intent();
        I.putExtra("result", number1-number2+"");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, I);
        finish();

    }

}
```

Comment: Why you do not want to use `startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: @Emmanuel just to know if i can do that or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between RequestCode and ResultCode is on the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))!

> requestCode:  The integer request code originally supplied to
> startActivityForResult(), allowing you to identify who this result
> came from
>
> resultCode:   The integer result code returned by the child
> activity through its setResult().